# Cannot get record if not matched in second table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel i want to get record from the first table even if it not exists in the second table but right now i'm getting the records only when if exist in both of the table
:

```
$module=DB::table('r_module')->leftJoin('r_perm','r_perm.module_id','=','r_module.id')->where('r_perm.role_id',$id)->orWhereNull('r_perm.role_id')->get();
```

Comment: use `toSql` and check your query is proper or not

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$module=DB::table('r_module')
   ->leftJoin('r_perm','r_perm.module_id','=','r_module.id')
   ->where('r_perm.role_id', $id)
   ->orWhere('r_perm.role_id', 'IS NULL')
   ->get();
```

You can also debug that query with 'dd()' function like this:

```
dd(DB::table('r_module')
   ->leftJoin('r_perm','r_perm.module_id','=','r_module.id')
   ->where('r_perm.role_id', $id)
   ->orWhere('r_perm.role_id', 'IS NULL')
   ->toSql());
```

That should put you on the track to make it generated as you need it.